# Python requests and streaming - AttributeError: 'X509' object has no attribute '_x509'

Tags: python, python-requests

Python requests is having issues:

```
rs = requests.get(STREAM_URL, stream=True,headers=headers)

Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "oanda_streaming_pairs_server.py", line 287, in multistreamer
    rs = requests.get(STREAM_URL, stream=True,headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 835, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 330, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 324, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 166, in get_subj_alt_name
    cert = _Certificate(openssl_backend, peer_cert._x509)
AttributeError: 'X509' object has no attribute '_x509'
```

Comment: issues with requests: had to use version 2.11.1 then worked.

Comment: did you find out why? I'm seeing this behavior on a ubnutu VM which has requests 2.12.1 also. Strange thing is. I have another VM with the same requests version 2.12.1, and there it works fine!!

Comment: no..I just checked the versions that were working on other servers and my local dev.  None had the latest version. I assume a bug in the code or compatibility with some dependency.

Comment: Seems more like a compatibility problem

Comment: It is ok you have `/usr/lib` vs `/usr/local/lib` ?

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it turned out that the version of pyOpenSSL was too old.  My Ubuntu 14.4 was running version 0.13 of pyOpenSSL.  I was getting the reported error with elasticsearch python library.

I had to update pyOpenSSL by running:

```
sudo pip install -U pyOpenSSL
```

You can check pyOpenSSL version with:

```
python -c 'import OpenSSL; print(OpenSSL.__version__)'
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, from: https://libraries.io/pypi/azure-cli-cloud

If you run into an AttributeError: 'X509' object has no attribute '_x509' error, downgrade your version of the requests library from 2.12.1 to 2.11.1. `Use pip install requests==2.11.1.`

Answer (score 2):

You need PyOpenSSL version at least 0.14.

Answer (score 0):

I had Cryptography v39 and my solution was to revert to v38

```
pip install "Cryptography==38"
```